# laravel how to store model and relation ids in session so you can get the relations again

Tags: php, session, laravel

I think I am doing this wrong because it seems too difficult...Basically I am writing my model and relation id's into a Session variable as an array of arrays and I want to load the models back when I retrieve the session data at the other end. Can I store my session data differently to make this easier?

This is how I store the array

`$bookingsPaymentPending[$attendee_id][] = $program_id;`

For 1 attendee (`id=416`) and 2 related programs (`id=2,4`), This gives me something like
`Array ( [416] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 ) )`

I am trying to turn that back into the collection of `$attendees-with('programs')` and the related programs using an Eloquent query

Something like

```
foreach ($bookingPaymentPending as $attendee_id => $program_ids)
    $attendee[]= Attendee::find($attendee)->with('program'=>function($q) use ($program_ids){
    $q->whereIn('id', $program_ids);
}
```

`

But it's not working and it's also just an array of `$attendees` and I probably want the collection.

Comment: I managed to do this successfully, you need to store `$attendees` collection as is in session variable along with relation, take a look at laravels [eager loading.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using serialization.

Using PHP serialize() on objects before you store them and unserialize() to reinstatiate them.

http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.serialization.php

Also see the docs here:

http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization

However, I really wouldn't recommend storing data in this way. Save your eloquent objects to the database and if you want to have them in the session just reference the id and grab it from the database when needed.